# How to evaluate $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{-h}^{h}f(t)dt?$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in\mathcal[-\pi,\pi].$ How to evaluate $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{-h}^{h}f(t)dt?$$

Comment: Please read about accepting answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 4):

Let $F(t)=\int f(t)dt$.
Then, 
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{-h}^{h}f(t)dt=2\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{F(-h+2h)-F(-h)}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0}2f(-h)=2f(0)$$